# Shutting down the PC from Java application

Tags: java, shutdown

I am trying to shut down my Ubuntu PC using a Java Application, but nothing seems to happen. Following is my code:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

try {
   Process proc = runtime.exec("sudo shutdown -h now");
}    
catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid that `sudo` asks for a password, edit the `sudoers` file with `visudo`:

```
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/shutdown
```

This will create a new file in the directory `/etc/sudoers.d/` which will be included, leaving your original `sudoers` file intact.

If your user is called `myuser` and your host is called `myhost` you could add these lines

```
myuser myhost = (root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown
myuser myhost = (root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot
```

Save your changes and try it out.

Also, you shouldn't do `e.printStackTrace()` but use a logger.